# Moving things between containers in responsive design (media queries, css)

Tags: html, css, media

Let's say I have a bunch of icons that are in my html header, but in a really small screen, I want to move those icons into footer, or body, or something. With media queries in css, is there a way to make those icons display in a place other than where they actually are in html (i.e. header)? Thanks!

Comment: can you have them in a div in both places, but set the display to none or otherwise in the CSS depending on the different sections describing the different screen sizes?

Comment: oh yeah, that's a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the icon bar in a div in the header and a div in the footer then in CSS do something like

```
/* for screens 480px or larger */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #header-icon-div {
        display:initial; /* you may want this to be block or inline-block */
    }
    #footer-icon-div {
        display:none;
    }
}
/* For screens less than 480px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header-icon-div {
        display:none;
    }
    #footer-icon-div {
        display:initial; /* you may want this to be block or inline-block */
    }
}
```